# DFSORT is giving SB37 repeatedly

Tags: mainframe, jcl, dfsort

When I am sorting a Variable length file, the job is abending with SB37 repeatedly. Even when I increased the SPACE parameter values, still the job is abending.

Can anyone please help me in knowing what could be the reason for this..?

Below is the JCL I have been trying.

```
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN    DD DSN=<Input DSN>,DISP=SHR   [the i/p DSN created with SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE) ]
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=<output DSN>,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             UNIT=DISK,SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE),
//             DCB=(RECFM=V,LRECL=32756,DSORG=PS)
//SYSIN     DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(1,15,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE
/*
//SYSOUT    DD  SYSOUT=*
```

Comment: Try asking where you work and also look at the sort manual; but what exactly is the message ???; Issues: you may need sort works; should the RECFM be VB ??; Is 32765 the correct block size ???; for VB files cols 1->4 hold the length !!! so if it is a VB file you are soring on record length. hava look at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.iceg200%2Fice1cg5010.htm

Comment: You need to include the sysout from the step in your question. If you are supposed to be using dynamic work files (which you must be, since you don't have any in the JCL), then don't add SORTWKnn files. You should also look at how much space your input file actually used, not just what it was defined with. Why is your LRECL so large? It will be using your DASD very inefficiently. Take not of @BruceMartin's comment about the RDW. Your (1,15,CH,A) looks wrong for variable-length records, unless you want them in record-length order as the major part of the key.

Comment: Hi Bill, I tried by adding the Sort work datasets earlier also. But it didn't work too.

As per your comment, I thought of reducing the record length and gave it a try. It is working. Let me explain the scenario here.

Comment: At first, my jcl will gets data from MQ. Here I am using 32756 as recod length. Then in the next step I am trying to remove the duplicates. As I am aware of the approximate record length of file, I reduced it to 500 while doing the SORT. And now it's working. So, I am thinking that this is not something really related to the lack of space. May be the process is getting into a loop due to the huge record length. And also the file generally contains around 3 lakh records.

Comment: And also, here is the error message displayed when the job abended initially.
"AN SB37  ABEND WAS ISSUED BY DFSORT, ANOTHER PROGRAM OR AN EXIT (PHASE S 3)"

Comment: I would like to see the entire sysout from your step, the first and the amended one, pasted into your question. There is an edit option beneath the question. My concern is that you may be truncating records without realising it. Be aware that an LRECL gives you 496 bytes of data. Oh, and don't scratch around hoping that it is some type of bug in the system software you are using. It is not.

Comment: @BillWoodger,, Infact, I will convert this file of record length 500 to 250 (rest of record will be spaces all the time) in the further steps using IEBGENER. so, I hope, I am not losing any data of the records. Because after 250, rest of the record would be filled with spaces and which won't be used. Still I will try to post the SYSOUT soon. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you intend to get rid of trailing blanks and only deal with a maximum data-length of 246, you should do it all in the SORT.

```
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN    DD DSN=<Input DSN>,DISP=SHR
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=<output DSN>,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             UNIT=DISK,SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE)
//SYSIN     DD *
  INREC BUILD=(1,4,5,246)
  SORT FIELDS=(5,246,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE
  OUTFIL VLTRIM=C' '
//SYSOUT    DD  SYSOUT=*
```

Note that I have removed the DCB information from SORTOUT. SORT will take care of that, and you confuse and increase maintenance by including it on SORTOUT (or any DD from OUTFIL) in a SORT step.

In the INREC, a new record is made from the input, which is 250 bytes long (four bytes of RDW and 246 bytes of data). The RDW and data are mentioned separately, so that it is clear to the next person along that you know what you are doing (and perhaps you really want 250 bytes of data anyway?).

In this way, all the data you do not want does not go into the SORT itself, massively reducing your workspace requirements, reducing CPU time, and elapsed time.

Unless your data has an actual key (in position 5 for a length of 11) you are potentially treating non-duplicate data as duplicate. In case you don't have a key, the SORT now sorts on the the data. There is no longer even a remote need to sort on the RDW, as all the RDWs will contain the record-length of 250 (in binary) in the first two bytes due to the BUILD on INREC.

The `SUM FIELDS=NONE` will now de-duplicate on the 246 bytes of data.

In `OUTFIL`, `VLTRIM=C' '` is used to remove any trailing spaces that happen to be left.

Being concerned that you are unsure of your actual record-lengths, I'd run something like this:

```
  INREC BUILD=(1,4,1,2) 

  SORT FIELDS=(5,2,BI,A) 

  OUTREC OVERLAY=(5:5,2,BI,EDIT=(IIIIT),10:18X)

  OUTFIL NODETAIL, 
         REMOVECC, 
         HEADER2=('RECLENS PRESENT ON FILE'), 
         SECTIONS=(5,5, 
             TRAILER3=(5,5)), 
         TRAILER1=('MIN/MAX ', 
             MIN=(5,5,ZD,EDIT=(IIIIT)), 
             ' ', 
             MAX=(5,5,ZD,EDIT=(IIIIT)))
```

This will produce a simple file, showing you all your record-lengths, and showing the minimum/maximum on the last page.

INREC is used to make records containing the (binary) record-length only. These are then SORTed. OUTREC expands the binary record-length to five printable digits with leading zeros suppressed. OUTFIL reporting features are used: detail lines are suppressed, no print control codes are included, a header is printed at the top of each "page", a control-break is established on the formatted record-length, and the record-length is printed when the break occurs. At the end, the minimum and maximum values are printed.

If you create the input for this with a SORT step consisting of this:

OPTION COPY
  OUTFIL VLTRIM=C' '

Then you will get a report of the record-lengths of your file once the trailing blanks are ignored, and can be confident (for that example of data) that what you know of the specification matches the data.

Comment: ,I have checked your new code. It is giving the record length as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, the SB37 could be because the sort work DDs don't get enought space when allocated dynamically.

```
/STEP01   EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN    DD DSN=<Input DSN>,DISP=SHR   [the i/p DSN created with SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE) ]
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=<output DSN>,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             UNIT=DISK,SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE),
//             DCB=(RECFM=V,LRECL=32756,DSORG=PS)
//SORTWK01 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(500,10))
//SORTWK02 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(500,10))
//SORTWK03 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(500,10))
//SORTWK04 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(500,10))
//SYSIN     DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(1,15,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE
/*
//SYSOUT    DD  SYSOUT=*
```

Comment: Difficult to be certain without the sysout, but I can't think of a real reason why the dynamic allocation of work space shouldn't work. If the particular default parameters for dynamic allocation do not give enough, they can be overridden for this particular step.

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since I've worked on a mainframe, but if memory serves a B37 can occur for two basic reasons:

1)  Disk space for an initial allocation is not available

2)  Disk space for a secondary allocation is not available

Your JCL statement:

```
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=<output DSN>,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             UNIT=DISK,SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE),
//             DCB=(RECFM=V,LRECL=32756,DSORG=PS)
```

Is asking for 1200 initial cylinders.  This seems like a lot of space, try something like:

```
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=<output DSN>,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             UNIT=DISK,SPACE=(CYL,(12,240),RLSE),
//             DCB=(RECFM=V,LRECL=32756,DSORG=PS)
```

This should get you a primary allocation and then 240 cylinders for each of the secondary allocations, if necessary.

Also, look up the exact description of SB37, it should describe when the problem is due to NO space for primary allocation versus no space for a secondary allocation.

Comment: If the file is that size, why would it seem like a lot of space? Did you try looking at the message yourself? Why not just wait for more information from OP, rather than making noisy guesses unlikely to be of use to many?

Comment: Because I don't have a messages manual.  The person asking the question should do the work.  Most of the SX37's are for those reasons.  Remember when hearing hoofs think horses not zebras.

Comment: There is no indication that the OP does not know what an SB37 is. Why I was asking you was to do with your point 1). You may not have a manual yourself, but IBM makes its manuals available for free. So you can have one (or thousands). You have given no explanation for why you suggest coding the `SPACE` like that. If DASD is properly managed, there is probably no reason to do that these days. In a poorly-managed development environment, perhaps. But no-one reading your answer will know if/when it is a good thing to do, because it lacks explanation.

Comment: Question was NOT about how to code JCL, however, how one writes a JCL statement does affect DASD allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JCL , I modified. And it is working.

Even, here also the record length (LRECL) of input dataset is 32756.

```
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN    DD DSN=<Input DSN>,DISP=SHR   [the i/p DSN created with SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE) ]
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=<output DSN>,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             UNIT=DISK,SPACE=(CYL,(1200,120),RLSE),
//             DCB=(RECFM=V,LRECL=500,DSORG=PS)
//SYSIN     DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(1,15,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE
/*
//SYSOUT    DD  SYSOUT=*
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion which would make me feel happier about how the records are cut-down in size.